# bigint(20) within sql query in R

Tags: r, bigint, rmysql

In my SQl base the type of the item_id  is bigint(20)
I need to extract a list of item_id and then insert it into another table to make a join then.

But R converts item_id into the "double" in the result of the query.

```
{query.1<-c("Select ITEM_ID FROM DISPLAY WHERE client_key=121")
query.1 <- paste (query.1, collapse = " ")
items<- dbGetQuery(connect.base, query.1)

typeof(items$ITEM_ID)
[1] "double"}
```

So I can't input this values into the new table as the join will not work 
there is no bigint(20) in R, so probably I need to convert to caracter, but how can i do it within RMySQL query?

Any help will be much appriciate

Comment: As I know, when inserting data from R into DB-table converting of data types is a matter of DBMS. If the type of column in your `data.frame` is `CAST`-able to the necessary one defined in DB-table properties, then inserting will be ok. Though convert to `character` or `integer` is quite simple: `items$ITEM_ID <- as.character(items$ITEM_ID)` or the same with `as.integer`, but, as I think, `as.integer` may cause an error because of big values in your `ITEM_ID` column.

Comment: "as.character" That is what I was doing, but it converted double numbers into charecters, so the final result was not correct to make a further join. The only solution that I had found is to cast(item_id as char) into sql query directly. and than define a column type as bigint(20) into dbWriteTable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a table in mysql with specified fields. Like

```
dbSendQuery(connect.base, "create table new_table(
ITEM_ID bigint not null,
key(ITEM_ID))ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;")
```

Then if you write a DB table with R using `append=TRUE` the value will be in the right format:

```
dbWriteTable(connect.base, "new_table",items, append=TRUE,row.names=F)
```